# Does a Greensting Slayer Magus qualify as having Sneak Attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, archetype

The [Magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/) archetype [Greensting Slayer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-magus-archetypes/greensting-slayer/) modifies their Arcane Pool in this way:

> At 1st level, a greensting slayer can expend 1 point from his arcane pool as a swift action to add 1d6 points of sneak attack damage to his next melee attack that round. The attack must meet all of the usual prerequisites for making a sneak attack, as the rogue class feature. For every 4 levels beyond 1st, the amount of sneak attack damage dealt by this ability increases by 1d6 (to a maximum of 5d6 at 17th level). If a greensting slayer gets a sneak attack from another source, the bonuses on damage stack.

Does Greensting Slayer Magus 5 have Sneak Attack 2d6, specifically, (assuming skill ranks are met and they chose Mage Hand as a Cantrip) would they qualify for the [Arcane Trickster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/arcane-trickster/) Prestige Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A [greensting slayer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-magus-archetypes/greensting-slayer/) [magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/) has no [sneak attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/#TOC-Sneak-Attack) until the magus spends a point from his arcane pool

Just like a creature that *can* cast an [*enlarge person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/) to become size Large does *not* mean the creature meets size Large requirements and prerequisites, being *able* to *gain* sneak attack under certain circumstances does *not* typically count as *having* sneak attack *now*.

A strict GM may allow such a creature to take its first level in the prestige class arcane trickster if the creature would [advance a level](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/) between sessions if the session ends during a melee round in which the ability sneak attack is gained from the magus's arcane pool *if* the creature also met the class's other requirements, but that's complicated and likely unreliable unless worked out first with the GM.

But a more generous GM may allow such a greensting slayer magus to meet the sneak attack requirements for the prestige class [arcane trickster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/arcane-trickster/) *anyway*—despite technically lacking sneak attack upon advancing a level—without feeling as though this will break the game. (Many *Pathfinder* prestige classes like the arcane trickster are usually *less* optimized than its core classes.)